# TIFF reading and writing TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP dependence

Tags: c++, io, tiff, libtiff

My code reads (`tiffIn`) and write (`tiffOut`) a tiff image line by line, I open a Tiff file with `#include "tiffio.h"` and read each tag and copy it exactly the same in the new tiff. The only tag that I change is:

```
int rows_per_strip = 65536 * 8 /(nc * nx * bps);
if (rows_per_strip == 0) rows_per_strip = 1;
```

where nc, nx, ny and bps are:

```
TIFFGetField (tiffIn, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &ny)
TIFFGetField (tiffOut, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &nx);
TIFFGetField (tiffOut, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, &bps);
TIFFGetField (tiffOut, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, &nc);
```

and `rows_per_strip` is:

```
TIFFSetField (tiffOut, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP,    rows_per_strip);
```

the for loop that reads and write can be summarized as:

```
for(int i = 0; i<ny; i++){
unsigned char * dataptr=new unsigned char[sll];
TIFFReadScanline(tiffIn, dataptr, line, 0);
TIFFWriteScanline (tiffOut, dataptr, line);
delete[] dataptr;
}
```

where `sll` is:

```
sll = (unsigned int) TIFFScanlineSize (tiffIn);
```

When I open the written TIFF file with gimp I get an error:

```
 Wrong "StripByteCounts" field, ignoring and calculating from imagelength
```

and the image is displayed in this way:

[image: wrongly written tiff]

but I read and write the tag with:

```
 unsigned short int stmp;
 unsigned short int striptBytesCount;

 TIFFGetField(tiffIn, TIFFTAG_STRIPBYTECOUNTS,&stmp);
 striptBytesCount=stmp;

 TIFFSetField (tiffOut, TIFFTAG_STRIPBYTECOUNTS, striptBytesCount);
```

So it should be right.
moreover, if I change the `rows_per_strip` tag, and assign `1`, the image is displayed correctly.

Comment: Your `for` loop has a gigantic memory leak, unless you called `delete []` in the loop somewhere.

Comment: Also, why did you start your loop at 1?  Shouldn't it start at 0?

Comment: I know about the memory leak, but since in the original code it was somewhat more complex I summarized as you saw. I will change it adding a delete[]

Comment: Changed the 1 with a 0. Again this is just a proof of concept

Comment: If you look at those scan lines that are off, they mimic the color scheme of the overall picture.  Looks like the lines are artifacts from existing lines or extended existing lines.  Maybe one of your "reads" failed or went off the rails and read too much data.

Comment: Corrected the possible memory leak, I know that this is not the most efficient solution anyway.

Comment: Update: the code now works with the latest update for ubuntu 14.04 of the libtiff library 4.0.3-7